# Is there any way to circumvent X-frame-options sameorigin?

Tags: web-applications, permissions, same-origin-policy

Is it possible to write a webapp, that can display third-party webpages without having to act as a proxy?

This comes up because I've seen services like comic-rocket.com* harmed by `X-frame-options: sameorigin`. While I perfectly understand, that this is an important security feature to prevent click-jacking, it also means, that webapps have lost a potentially important capability compared to native applications.

Using the server of the service as a proxy would certainly be a solution, but would significantly ramp up data usage, as all resources would have to be redirected through the proxy as well to prevent same-origin issues on embedded resources. Furthermore, websites may block such behaviour. Legal implications are unclear too. A server-side solution is thus probably unviable.

So I was wondering: Is there any method to obtain permission from the user to ignore X-frame-options? Would it be possible with PWAs?

---

* Not affiliated. I am merely a user of the service, but interested in what I may suggest to them as a solution, or what I may even be able to do on my side with bookmarklets / Tampermonkey.

As a little historical note, previously webpages now affected by the X-frame-options setting used to redirect the toplevel frame to themselves, which in the case of comic-rocket.com ultimately affected the user-experience less. Sadly, the ability of redirecting toplevel URLs has become a big issue with malicious ads, and apparently has also been blocked.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, just use my [X-Frame-Bypass](https://github.com/niutech/x-frame-bypass) Web Component, which works in the latest Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: It does not work (anymore?), at least in my up to date FF and Chromium.